# How to get background image for a span or li to appear in the top, above the text?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have this item in a horizontal navigation menu:

```
<li class="menu">
   <a href="---">Our Users</a>
</li>
```

I want it to appear like this:

[image: screenshot]

I will figure out the text color, etc. What I want to know is, how to have the image appear above the text, and the text centered below it.

Any advice?

Comment: Can you jsfiddle the actual example? Or post the code? Where's that image coming from, etc?

Comment: @99miles The image is just an image in a folder. Code is too long to be put in jsfiddle but what I've posted is the essence of it. Its a UL with a bunch of LIs, each LI having an image on top and text below, same as the screenshot.

Comment: You hadn't specified that the image was in the ul. And, it shouldn't be much code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
Assuming your image is not clickable...
apply width and padding to you li tag.

```
li { background: url(urimage.png) no-repeat; 
 padding: 72px 0 0 0; 
 text-align: center;
 width: 100px;
 list-style: none;
```

}

If you want your image to be clickable just wrap your text "our users" into a div and apply same style as above.

[Try this jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ydx47/)

hope it'll help you. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Its easy set the background of the li to be that 2 man icon and give a padding-top for li.

```
li { background: url(image.png) no-repeat; 
     padding: 40px 0 0 0; 
     text-align: center;
   }
```